# How do you remove the scrollbars on timeline.js iframe?

Tags: iframe, scrollbar, timeline.js

I tried posting this to the timeline.js Google group but it got deleted.

I'm seeing scrollbars on the outer iFrame on the plugin's website (http://timeline.verite.co) and on our test site.

When embedding the iframe into our site I tried adding:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="overflow:visible;"
```

But while the scrollbars disappear, the right edge gets cut off slightly.

Also, the suggested embed code has width="100%".

- If I reduce this to 95%
- The iframe is much smaller than the containing div
- but the right edge still gets cut off slightly
- We see this in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac
- We also see the scrollbars in our preview on the timeline.js website

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't see anything on the timeline.js site or in the Google Group - except a few "you're doing it wrong" comments for other posts.

Is there a trick to removing scrollbars in iFrames? Sorry if this is simple.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width, height and frameborder in your iframe as shown below

```
width='100%' height='700' frameborder='0'
```

Try this, i think now it's works

```
<iframe src='embed.verite.co/timeline/?source=0Aj2TitNEGaD2dHlqV3ZRcDhMYlY3MjZmUEt2aWQ0ckE&font=Bevan-PotanoSans&maptype=toner&lang=en' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am already using the full embed code from the site which includes those items: `<iframe width='100%' height='500' frameborder='0' scrolling="no" style="overflow:visible;"></iframe>`

Comment: Try this, Remove scrolling and change style="overflow:hidden;"

Comment: Thanks heaps. I tried your suggestions but the right edge still gets cut off (looks like by 1px) and scrollbars appear in Safari and Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: Thanks - this removes the scrollbars but crops the right-hand edge: `<iframe src='http://embed.verite.co/timeline/?source=0Aj2TitNEGaD2dHlqV3ZRcDhMYlY3MjZmUEt2aWQ0ckE&font=PT&maptype=toner&lang=en&start_zoom_adjust=5&height=500' width='100%' height='500' frameborder='0' scrolling="no" style="overflow:visible;"></iframe>`

Comment: Try this and let me know                                      <iframe src='http://embed.verite.co/timeline/?source=0Aj2TitNEGaD2dHlqV3ZRcDhMYlY3MjZmUE‌​t2aWQ0ckE&font=PT&maptype=toner&lang=en&start_zoom_adjust=5&width=100&height=500' width='100%' height='500' frameborder='0' scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden;"></iframe>'

Comment: Thanks heaps. Your iframe code sort of collapses the entire iframe in on itself. If I could post a screenshot I would but it ends up being sized to the minimum size with scrollbars - about 100px W x 240px H. Here is the link to the Google spreadsheet - it's just a straight copy (with updated data) of the example spreadsheet on the timeline.js website: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Aj2TitNEGaD2dHlqV3ZRcDhMYlY3MjZmUEt2aWQ0ckE&output=html

Comment: Try this, i think now it's work <iframe src='http://embed.verite.co/timeline/?source=0Aj2TitNEGaD2dHlqV3ZRcDhMYlY3MjZmUEt2aWQ0ckE&font=Bevan-PotanoSans&maptype=toner&lang=en' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>

Comment: OK, this now works - thank you. How do I give your last comment credit as the initial answer doesn't work - I don't really understand this aspect to Stack Overflow sorry.

Comment: @CMSCSS i will edit my ans. you just approve that, then credits will come automatically..:-)